# How to open a mxml page on a button click event in Adobe flash?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have 2 buttons on my main page (main.mxml).
When i click on btn1 it has to show btn1_main.mxml , and similarly on click of btn2 I want btn2_main.mxml.
Both these btn1_main.mxml and btn2_main.mxml are in ./components

I have created event listenteners on the the mouse click for the buttons.
Want to know what should i do to open the new page when event handler is executing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this

1. Place  btn1_main.mxml and  btn2_main.mxml in a ViewStack and change the index of viewStack upon button Click.

Example

```
<mx:ViewSatck width="100%" height="100%" id="vs">
      <components:btn1_Main/>
      <components:btn2_Main/>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Now in btn1 Click Handler --> vs.selectedIndex = 0; and in btn2 click 
hanlder--> vs.selectedIndex = 1;

2. Place the 2 mxmls in main.mxml and set visible and includeInLayout true whenever the repective button is clicked

Example

```
<components:btn1_Main id="m1" visible="false" includeInLayout="false"/>
<components:btn2_Main id="m2" visible="false" includeInLayout="false"/>
```

Now, in btn1 Click Handler --> m1.visible = true;m1.includeInLayout =true; m2.visible = false;m2.includeInLayout =false

Now in btn1 Click Handler --> m1.visible = false;m1.includeInLayout =false; m2.visible = true;m2.includeInLayout =true